# Iphone facebook connect example does't call login screen. Why?

Tags: iphone, facebook

i added [self fbButtonClick:nil]; , but it does't call login screen. Why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
  [self.label setText:@"Please log in"];
  _getUserInfoButton.hidden = YES;
  _getPublicInfoButton.hidden = YES;
  _publishButton.hidden = YES;
  _uploadPhotoButton.hidden = YES;
  _fbButton.isLoggedIn = NO;
  [_fbButton updateImage];

   [self fbButtonClick:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're suppose to call the `authorize` method on the _facebook object to login. That will call the login screen

Comment: [self fbButtonClick:nil]; calls authorize method , but login screen doesn't appear. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem with timer

```
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.001
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:NO] retain];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{   
  [timer invalidate];
  [timer release];
  timer = nil;

  [self fbButtonClick:nil];
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting the code you have in the timer in either the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` delegate methods? Using a timer "smells" wrong.

Comment: I put NSTimer in the  viewDidLoad method . It smells wrong , but it solves the problem. Can you suggest more elegant decisions?